# SQLITE between date different result

Tags: android, sqlite

this is a part of my db and i want to obtain a query like this:

```
select * from  tb_store where data_in between '01-01-2014 00:00:00' AND '01-01-2025 23:59:59'
```

but the problem is that if the value of the second data are 20-03-2016 23:59:59 (present in the table only the day) the result are ok, otherwise if  the data are 05-03-2016 23:59:59 the result are like this:

```
zabajone    01-01-2015 11:48:28
```

I use this data model "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" 
where is the problem?

```
       nome              data_in
fior di panna   11-01-2015 11:48:28
cassata         11-01-2015 11:48:28
nocciola        10-01-2015 19:54:09
bacio           14-01-2015 15:13:21
malaga          09-04-2015 13:56:38
cioccolato      09-01-2015 12:04:28
limone          18-01-2015 12:44:54
gogonzola       10-02-2015 19:55:34
pistacchio      10-03-2015 19:54:58
zabajone        01-01-2015 11:48:28
```

Comment: Are you saying there aren't any records from `01-01-2014` to `01-01-2015`? If so then you are right and there's no question here, otherwise your question isn't too clear.

Comment: Your date format is completely wrong. The correct one is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) a list of supported formats for dates in SQLite:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

You're using something that's not supported. Try reversing the date so you get:

```
between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-01 23:59:59'
```